# How can I import the data of postgreSQL to Struts2-jquery-grid?

Tags: jakarta-ee, jquery-plugins, struts2, ognl, struts2-jquery

I have a database and can see a complete HTML table using struts and jsp.

Now, I would want to configure a struts2-jquery-grid with the same data. Could someone help me? I have been searching for days and couldn't find this task.

Here is my action:

```
    package sead.painel.actions.dpp;

    import java.util.List;

    import org.apache.struts2.convention.annotation.Action;
    import org.apache.struts2.convention.annotation.ParentPackage;
    import org.apache.struts2.convention.annotation.Result;
    import sead.painel.dao.ConcursoDAO;
    import sead.painel.modelo.dpp.Concurso;

    import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport;

    @ParentPackage("default")
    public class ListaConcursos extends ActionSupport {
       /**
       * 
       */
       private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
       private List<Concurso> concursos;


       @Action(value="lista-concursos", results={
        @Result(name="success", location="lista-concursos.jsp")
       })


       public String execute(){    

       concursos = new ConcursoDAO().getLista();
       return "success";
       }

       public List<Concurso> getConcursos() {
       return concursos;
       }

       public void setConcursos(List<Concurso> concursos) {
       this.concursos = concursos;
       }
    }
```

And here the jsp:

```
    <%@taglib prefix="sj" uri="/struts-jquery-tags" %>
    <%@taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags" %>
    <%@taglib prefix="sjg" uri="/struts-jquery-grid-tags" %>

    <head>
    <sj:head jqueryui="true" jquerytheme="redmond" />
    </head>

    <sj:a href="dpp/concursos" targets="tone">Voltar</sj:a>

    <s:url action="lista-concursos" id="listaConcursos" />

    <sjg:grid 

    gridModel="dpp/lista-concursos" 
    href="%{listaConcursos}"
    caption="Lista de Concursos"
    rowList="10, 15, 20"
    rowNum="10"
    rownumbers="true"
    pager="true"
    dataType="json">

    <sjg:gridColumn name="nome" index="nome" title="Nome" dataType="text" value="#concurso.nome" />
    <sjg:gridColumn name="codigo" index="codigo" title="Codigo" dataType="json" value="#concurso.codigo" />


</sjg:grid>
```

The grid doesn't load anything. But I can load data in a HTML table with .

Comment: You're asking how to use the jquery grid plugin? Like shown [here](http://www.weinfreund.de/struts2-jquery-grid-showcase/index.action) that has source you can download?

Comment: Yes, i am. I want to use struts2-jquery-grid-plugin like this example. But i don´t know how to do it. I have tried to follow some examples but i didn´t get it.

Comment: What happens? Anything in the JavaScript console? What does the action render, JSON? (And is the response type marked as such? Why not use the JSON plugin?)

Comment: The action generate a list and i can show it with html. When I set return type for json in the action, i get NullPointerException error.

Comment: Just saying you get an NPE doesn't help.

Comment: No. I´m gettin an NPE, but don´t know why!
I have POJO and DAO class, action, and JSP. The action and JSP code is described above, but I don´t know if it is correct.

Comment: Well I don't know why either; I can't see your code, or the exception, or your configuration.

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you can see the data in an HTML table, you are in the right way, but you still need to do something more.

In order to fill the jquery-grid with your data, that data must be in JSON format, so **the first you must do is to enable JSON suppport** in your Struts2 webapplication.

Although there are many guides, I advise you that [one](https://code.google.com/p/struts2-jquery/wiki/GridTag) to go in depth with jquery-grid.

But as you are beginner, you'll maybe have troubles adding new jars to your project, dependencies, and so forth. So, the best you can do is **download the code-example from the download section** of the above page (also [here](https://code.google.com/p/struts2-jquery/downloads/list)). There you'll find a lot of resources, but choose for example

```
struts2-jquery-grid-showcase-3.5.1.war
```

and import this .war file into your favourite development IDE. You'll see it working like a charm, with needed jar files and dependencies (you can copy them to your project).

Hope this help you.

Answer (score 0):

```
gridModel="lstUserBean"
```

This lstUserBean should be a list of UserBean, whose data the grid will show. This list should have getter/setter and the href attribute of sjg:grid should point to this action, and this action should return a JSON result.A single UserBean object will be shown as a single row of data, so make sure all attrribute names matches with the name attribute of sjg:gridColumn and those attributes have appropriate getters in UserBean class.

Here are a [few more examples](http://www.onlinexamples.com/searchaction.action?idlabels=21&label=struts2jquery). You will find a number of grids there along with project source code.

Comment: XCoder, thanks for the attention. I am beginner =)
I didn´t understand exactly where is my error code. Is in jsp? or in the action? I need to develop something more, like other class or action?

Comment: error is in gridModel and whatever is defined in gridModel should be a List of Bean in an action with getter and setter. Have you looked at [those examples](http://www.onlinexamples.com/searchaction.action?idlabels=21&label=struts2jquery).